# Remove percentage of items in a list randomly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one list of n elements. Now I have to remove a percentage of all the elements in this list. The removed elements have to be all randomly picked.

For example, let n = 0,2 (20% to be deleted)

```
n = 0.2
list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
```

After the randomly removed 20%, the list will be:

```
list = [one, three, four, five, seven, eight, nine, ten] # two and seven deleted
```

Now you probably think, mmm this isn't that hard... Well it all has to be done in one line and I am kinda new to those oneliners...

So a new function has to be made which returns the same list but without a percentage of the elements:

```
def remove(n, list):
    return list # But the new list with elements removed
```

Please help, what to type behind the return?

Comment: "Well it all has to be done in one line" And why is that?

Comment: It *doesn't* have to be done on one line, and it *probably shouldn't*. Is this an actual requirement? And what is the context of this requirement? A code golf competition? I hope not school or work...

Comment: Also, `n = 0,2` makes `n` a *`tuple`*, I think you meant `n = 0.2`

Comment: It all has to be done in one line because my assignment says so... Else I'll fail the assignment.

Comment: @JoepGroentesoep your teacher is very demanding. Is he a stackoverflow member ? :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Probably, please don't stalk him. He's just a good guy with a little weird obsession for one-liners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use `random.sample` to pick `(100*(1-n))%` items:

```
import random

def remove(l,n):
    return random.sample(l,int(len(l)*(1-n)))

print(remove(list(range(1,11)),0.2))
```

result:

```
[10, 8, 4, 7, 1, 9, 6, 2]
```

beware of float to integer rounding though, you may throw in a `int(len(l)*(1-n)+0.5)` to avoid truncation and get nearest instead.

EDIT: another approach would be to `pop` the computed number of items at random indexes (recomputing the `len` of the list each time is simpler, to avoid index out of bounds):

```
def remove(l,n):
    for _ in range(int(len(l)*n)):
        l.pop(random.randrange(0,len(l)))
    return l
```

not a list comprehension, not one-liner, but works in-place. Maybe faster when the percentage of items to remove is low.

Comment: Although, technically this doesn't return the same list with the elements removed, but I'm not sure if that is an actual requirement

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right, but we all know what to answer when someone tries to remove elements from a list: use a listcomp instead. Another possibility would be to `pop` 2 random elements from the list. See my edit. 5 upvotes I have the duty to propose that too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import random
list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
new_list = [b for b in list if b not in [random.choice(list) for i in range(int(len(list)*0.2))]]
```

Output:

```
['one', 'three', 'four', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on whether the 'one line' has to be after the `return`, this list comprehension uses `lst.pop(i)` to remove the items at the randomly generated fraction of indcies `i` in one line, sorting indices in reverse to pop last to first avoiding possible index out of range error

```
lst = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]

def remove(n, lst):
    [lst.pop(i) for i in sorted(random.sample(range(len(lst)), k=int(len(lst)*n)),
                                reverse=True)]
    return lst 

remove(0.2, lst)
Out[37]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
```

and we modified `lst` itself:

```
lst
Out[38]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
```

refresh `lst`:

```
lst = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
```

and feed `remove()` a copy of `lst`

```
remove(0.2, lst[:])
Out[40]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'six', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
```

and the original list is presrved:

```
lst
Out[41]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
```

if the problem really, really specifies only a line of code, inline with the `return` then you  could abuse the inline if-else:

```
def remove(n, lst):
    return lst if [lst.pop(i) 
                   for i in sorted(random.sample(range(len(lst)),
                                                 k=int(len(lst)*n)),
                                   reverse=True)] else lst
```